# QWebView,How to determine whether this link is a new window?

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qwebpage, qtnetwork

code

```
  News::News(QWidget *parent) :
   QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::News)
  {
   ui->setupUi(this);
   ui->webView->page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks);
   connect(ui->webView,SIGNAL(linkClicked(QUrl)),this,SLOT(openUrl(QUrl)));
  }

void News::openUrl(QUrl url){
  if(the new window)
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
  }else{
    ui->webView->load(url);
  }
}
```

How do I judge instead of a new window link function openUrl?
How I'm going to write this code、?
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inherit your own class from QWebView and reimplement the createWindow() method. http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebview.html#createWindow

Comment: When the new window, and how to obtain the URL?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "when the new window". The QWebView will set the URL that is being opened to the QWebView you returned the pointer to. If you need to know the URL you can catch one of the signals of QWebPage that get emitted during the loading of the page and query the URL.

Comment: I need to do a browser, click on the url now all load handling.How do I handle better? <a  href='url' target='_blank' /> or <a herf='url' />

Comment: I just told you. Reimplement the createWindow(). In the reimplemented method construct a new QWebView instance. Call show() for it. Return the pointer. The QWebView will automatically set the URL for the QWebView you returned.

Comment: thanks,I'am try WebPage::acceptNavigationRequest and WebPage::createWindow.